# How to get UserID of Mail-User via powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

Using Powershell, how can I get the UserID of an account if I don't know which domain it is in?

For example, I have a Mail-User account called `b.newhart` and I can fetch information using that as the `-identity` with the `get-recipient` command.

But I need to know the UserID which has the domain name attached to it - for example, `b.newhart@mydomain.com`.  This is the *UserID* that you can see in the Admin panel of Exchange Online.

The reason I need the UserID is so I can use `Set-MsolUserPassword` on that account.  To use this command, I need to specify the `-UserPrincipalName` which is the `UserID`.  For full o365 accounts (with mail) I can use just the identity, but for Mail-User accounts I need the `UserID` with the domain name too, not just the identity.

We have very many mail-users from various domains, and the usernames are all standardized first initial + last name.  So if I can reset their passwords by just knowing their identity then it would be wonderful.

So, How can I get the the `UserID` of a Mail-User account?  OR how can I reset the password for a Mail-User account without knowing the domain designation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is!

```
get-recipient -identity b.newhart | select windowsLiveID
#returns b.newhart@mydomain.com
```

This will fetch the internal email address which is the UserID that can be used in the `Set-MsolUserPassword` command.